# Apache RewriteLog only on specific IP?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have logging enabled in my httpd conf file as follows...

```
RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

This works fine. I don't want to impact the server whilst debugging though, or create extra info than needed.

Is there any way to only log rewrites only for a specific IP address (or narrow via some other criteria if not)?

Answer (score 0):

One solution I've found so far is the pipe operator, so I've added the following...

```
RewriteLog "|/bin/grep '<myIpAddress>' > /var/log/httpd/debugrewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 5
```

Not sure how efficient that is, as it calls grep each time, so I'm not a fan of it, but for the moment its helping cut down the logging, and I turn it off as soon as finished.